# Reactnative App background app screenshot

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

In react-native, I'm developing an app. I want to capture a screen from another app and share it within my app without first going to the photographs folder.

I want to share a paytm/phonepe discount with my family and friends, for instance, therefore is it possible to open the phonepe app in my app and take a picture of the coupons to share via my app?
If not, please advise how I may accomplish something in React-Native.

Please friends
Thank you

for example my app XYZ is open and i want to share the paytm/phonepe coupon to my family/friend, so by programatly possibe i open phonepeapp  in  my app and capture the screen shot of the  coupons and share a screenshote via my app?